# Edge labels in networkx not on edges

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I'm gonna start by saying that we are extremely new to this as we are taking a high school python class right now. We are collectively working on a project given by our teacher that requires us to make a sort of map from a table that was given to us on repl.it. We plotted the map using networkx and matplotlib but whenever we try to add a label to the edges it does not plot properly. (This is our first time using these modules)

Edit: Turns out one of our project members messed with the code before i posted it. We now have the labels mostly on the lines but the spacing is still incorrect meaning most of it is unreadable. Basically we are now wondering how to properly format the graph so that it's readable and the spacing is correct. I updated the code below

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use('Agg')
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import replit as re

df = pd.read_csv('map.txt')

df = df.nsmallest(129,'startbuilding')
print(df)
startb = df.loc[:,'startbuilding']
endb = df.loc[:,'EndBuilding']
totd = df.loc[:,'TOTDIS']
outd = df.loc[:,'OUTDis']

print("Loading...")
re.clear()
G = nx.DiGraph()
plt.figure()

nodes = []



for i in range(len(startb)):
  if startb[i] not in nodes:
    nodes.append(startb[i]) 


print(nodes)


G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

for i in (range(len(startb))):
  G.add_edge(startb[i],endb[i],length=totd[i])


pos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=2, k=None, fixed=None, iterations=50, weight='weight', scale=2.0)






nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos = pos ,font_size = 3)


plt.axis('off')
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True,pos = pos)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('map.png')
```

The spacing is weird and the graph is unreadable:
[image: The spacing is weird and the graph is unreadable]

Comment: It might be counterintuitive, but the labels are rotated 90deg from the direction of the edges.

Comment: How does one fix that exactly

Comment: Can you explain how you want it to appear?  What do you mean by "spacing is incorrect"?

Comment: The font size in `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, font_size= 3)` is really really tiny.

Comment: In `nx.spring_layout` better use `weight=None` so edge lengths will be more or less equal

Comment: Maybe you can shorten the labels? Now they are too long to get something readable on this scale.

Answer (score 0):

Aight so turns out that we just ended up plotting each node individually and abandoning the plotting algorithms and it works great now. Thanks to everyone who responded for the advice